# Convert String containing list of JSON objects to Object Array

Tags: javascript, json

A String contains list of Objects which are serialized in JSON format, how to convert that to list of JSON Objects like given in example below preferably without using jQuery.

Eval, Stringyfy Json.parse etc dont seems to help here.

```
    [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];
```

Update:- JSON String

```
[
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6yAAA"},"Name":"Stella Pavlova","Phone":"(212) 842-5500","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6yAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6zAAA"},"Name":"Lauren Boyle","Phone":"(212) 842-5500","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6zAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt70AAA"},"Name":"Babara Levy","Phone":"(503) 421-7800","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt70AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt71AAA"},"Name":"Josh Davis","Phone":"(503) 421-7800","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt71AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt72AAA"},"Name":"Jane Grey","Phone":"(520) 773-9050","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt72AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt73AAA"},"Name":"Arthur Song","Phone":"(212) 842-5500","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt73AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt74AAA"},"Name":"Ashley James","Phone":"+44 191 4956203","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt74AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt75AAA"},"Name":"Tom Ripley","Phone":"(650) 450-8810","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt75AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt76AAA"},"Name":"Liz D'Cruz","Phone":"(650) 450-8810","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt76AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt77AAA"},"Name":"Edna Frank","Phone":"(650) 867-3450","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt77AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt78AAA"},"Name":"Avi Green","Phone":"(212) 842-5500","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt78AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt79AAA"},"Name":"Siddartha Nedaerk","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt79AAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt7AAAQ"},"Name":"Jake Llorrac","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt7AAAQ"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6rAAA"},"Name":"Rose Gonzalez","Phone":"(512) 757-6000","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6rAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6sAAA"},"Name":"Sean Forbes","Phone":"(512) 757-6000","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6sAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6tAAA"},"Name":"Jack Rogers","Phone":"(336) 222-7000","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6tAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6uAAA"},"Name":"Pat Stumuller","Phone":"(014) 427-4427","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6uAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6vAAA"},"Name":"Andy Young","Phone":"(785) 241-6200","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6vAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6wAAA"},"Name":"Tim Barr","Phone":"(312) 596-1000","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6wAAA"},
    {"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Contact/0039000000wvt6xAAA"},"Name":"John Bond","Phone":"(312) 596-1000","CreatedDate":"2014-05-15T06:17:48.000+0000","Id":"0039000000wvt6xAAA"}
]
```

Comment: So, this is your String?

Comment: this will be output of the conversion

Comment: If all of eval, Stringyfy and Json.parse fail, i'm sure you're the doing doing it wrong.

Comment: _Eval, Stringyfy Json.parse fail_: What did you try and what problem did you face?

Comment: JSON.parse is the way to do what you're trying to do. Post your string and I'm sure someone can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Nivas Javascript throws some or the other error

Comment: I think your intention is to resolve the error. For that, please post your code and the error that you need help with.

Comment: @Ganesh again its an json object

Comment: "*some or the other error*" is as useful as "*something is wrong with my code*". In other words: **what** error?

Comment: @AneeshA.E It's a string received from server side call.

Comment: That's not a string, that's an array of objects. You're already done if that's what you're starting with.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It actually fails an Angular controller. So the error message we see is not exact representation of actual error.

Comment: @Ganesh: will you bale set this into a js variable?

Comment: @Aneesh A.E I couldn't get you.

Comment: try setting ur "json string" into a variable and get the length.

Comment: @AneeshA.E, It doesn't allow .length, may be it's a JSON, & not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your post to make it more visibly clear, so maybe now you'll see: The value you posted as your "JSON String" is actually a JavaScript array of objects; exactly what you're claiming you're trying to convert the string into. You should read up more on JSON so you fully understand how you can convert to and from JSON, but that's already a valid JavaScript object -- you don't need to do anything to it.

Here's a JSFiddle showing this fact in action -- all you need to do is set a variable equal to the block of code you're receiving, and you can access it as a normal array/object. http://jsfiddle.net/ZpXVh/

```
var array = /* your really long code */;
alert(array[1]['name'];
```